# Joining two results sets in mysql without join or union

Tags: php, mysql

I have two results sets below.

```
SELECT * FROM `mfw_host`
 WHERE host_id IN
(SELECT host_id FROM `latest_tech` 
WHERE `nav_node_id` = 213)



SELECT * FROM `mfw_navnode`
 WHERE host_id  IN
(SELECT host_id FROM mfw_host
WHERE host_id IN (SELECT host_id FROM `latest_tech` 
WHERE `nav_node_id` = 213))
```

What I is to join both results together..without join and union  (because they have no keys connecting them..and the fields are different for each set of results).

How can I achieve so?

**UPDATE:....
ANSWER UPDATED SEE ABOVE..**

I want to add the results above from two sets together..they return 5 rows each, and have different column number retrieved each

Tried one solution:

```
SELECT
    a.*
  , b.*
FROM
  ( SELECT * FROM `mfw_host`
 WHERE host_id IN
(SELECT host_id FROM `latest_tech` 
WHERE `nav_node_id` = 213)
  ) AS a
  CROSS JOIN
  ( SELECT * FROM `mfw_navnode`
 WHERE host_id  IN
(SELECT host_id FROM mfw_host
WHERE host_id IN (SELECT host_id FROM `latest_tech` 
WHERE `nav_node_id` = 213))
  ) AS b
```

This cross join returns too many rows

Comment: Um..if the fields are different for each set of results and there are no keys connecting them, then you can't? Except on the PHP side.

Comment: How many rows does each query return?

Comment: So, you want 4x4 = 16 rows in the result? You can use a `CROSS JOIN`.

Comment: You said *"no keys connecting them"* and now you update and both have `host_id` ...

Comment: The have host_id... but their is no primary or foriegn keys... so no connection

Comment: @Dmitry: Please clarify what you want. Add the 5 rows from the first and the 5 from the second query and what you want as expected result. We have psychic powers but they are not working at this moment.

Answer (score 2):

You can fetch some default values for fields not existing in other query. Let's assume in mfw_host you have fields: id, hostname, ip; in mfw_navnode you have id, name, create_date. Then your query could be

```
SELECT 0 AS type, id, host_name, ip, '' AS node_name, 
    NULL AS create_date FROM mfw_host
WHERE host_id IN (
    SELECT host_id FROM `latest_tech` WHERE `nav_node_id` = 213)
UNION
SELECT 1 AS type, id, '' AS host_name, NULL AS ip, node_name, create_date 
    FROM `mfw_navnode` WHERE `parent_id`=213
```

Type is to allow you to know from which table is which row. But it's not necessary.

Comment: ummm.. so I could defined some default values that dont exist in the other table... will it retrieve me empty results? in the result set.... I think it would..so I think your solution could be the right one ...although very indirect..I might try it. There might be a better solution though